# Phonegap barcode prompts to enter value

Tags: phonegap-plugins, qr-code

Am using [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) in a phonegap app to scan QR codes.

When firing the scanner using:

```
function scan() {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
  );
 }
```

The camera doesn't start - I just get a prompt saying:

```
"Enter barcode value (empty value will fire handler)"
```

Any ideas welcome TQ

Answer (score 0):

The prompt says "Enter barcode value (empty value will fire handler)" maybe because you run platform browser. I' ve got the same "problem" when i run my project with "cordova run browser", and "browser" is a platform installed.